# Speed comparison of both voyagers

Tags: speed, interstellar-travel, space-probe

I came across [this](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/where/) page which provides (mostly extrapolated) speeds of both voyagers. Assuming they are fairly accurate, any reason why the speed of Voyager 2 (5-6 km/sec) is less than that of Voyager 1 (13 km/sec).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice carefully, you'll see that their speeds away from the sun are fairly similar (7-9 km/s), and the difference is only in their speeds away from the earth. This is because of a small component of earth's motion around the sun (which is at about 30 km/s) adding to Voyager 1's motion and subtracting from Voyager 2's motion.